# Accessing Intranet web application from salesforce

Tags: visualforce

I'm new in salesforce world.
i have question about salesforce and we implemented  for sales and service team.

my question is: 
 we have internal portal web site for employee and knowledge management. can we open it from salesforce? the web application that we access using lcoal IP address(ex: 192.168.50.148/internalPortal)

let's say user only can access the internal web site when they are in office and using our network.
and we don't have Public IP address.

how can i make user can access the web address in salesforce tab?

regards:
Willy

Answer (score 0):

You can always just create a new Visualforce page and use a standard HTML iframe.

```
<apex:page>
    <iframe src="https://192.168.1.1/" ></iframe>
</apex:page>
```

It will need to be an https URL, otherwise you'll end up with a "The page https://... was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from http://..."

Another issue might be if your https URL utilizes a valid SSL cert or not.  If it isn't valid and by navigating to the URL in a new browser tab yields any sort of browser warnings about the site being invalid (Chrome will say something like "This page might not be what you think it is.").  The page won't load until you accept this warning - your users will experience this too.

Comment: Hi @kirkevonphilly,
already tried using iframe tag. but it still cannot load the internal webpage.
the iframe come up with blank section.
any Idea?

Comment: That's that second part I was talking about - if you copy and paste the iframe src URL into a new tab and hit enter, what happens?

On the page with the iframe, after it loads, if you open up Chrome's Dev Tools and go to the Console tab, does it offer up any clues (look for red)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a web tab. Iframe is not a good option as it has its own limitation most of the time double scroll bar looks ugly and scripts won't run until sandbox property is set.

go to set up -> create -> tab -> web tab.

add that tab to remote site and in CORS just in case WEBSERVICE call needed.